# How to set custom name, suffix for mapper files and interfaces in mybatis generator?

Tags: orm, mybatis, ibatis, mapper, mybatis-generator

Can you set custom suffix and naming rule mapper xml and interfaces in MyBatis Generator (MBG)?

For example, When generating mapper files for class Book. MBG generates mapper file BookMapper.xml and interface PartnerDao.java. However, I wish to change the suffix to something else, like BookMapperBase.xml or BookDaoBase.xml,  and PartnerMapperBase.java or PartnerDaoBase.java.

The reason is, former colleagues were using BookMapper.xml for their hand-written sql statements and using the same name would cause confusion. Moreover, I do not wish to use generated mappers directly, but use custom mapper files that extend BookMapperBase.xml.

I have searched online and found some github [projects](https://github.com/dcendents/mybatis-generator-plugins) and [hot rod ORM](https://hotrod.sourceforge.io), but is it really not supported by official Mybatis Generator? If not, what is your recommended alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

1. You could use a domain object renaming rule as documented here: http://www.mybatis.org/generator/configreference/domainObjectRenamingRule.html
2. If that doesn't work the way you want it to, you could write a MyBatis Generator plugin to change the names of the generated artifacts. There is an example here: https://github.com/mybatis/generator/blob/master/core/mybatis-generator-core/src/main/java/org/mybatis/generator/plugins/RenameExampleClassPlugin.java